# php soap - send request for multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, soap, multidimensional-array, nusoap

First up, I'm trying to send a soap request using PHP SOAP and the XML that the service accepts is as shown below.

```
<U_MemberReservedTransaction xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <UserID>string</UserID>
  <password>string</password>
  <memberReservedTransactionRequest>
    <memberReservedTransactions>
      <ReservedType>string</ReservedType>
      <Firstname>string</Firstname>
      <Surname>string</Surname>
      <IcNew>string</IcNew>
    </memberReservedTransactions>
    <memberReservedTransactions>
      <ReservedType>string</ReservedType>
      <Firstname>string</Firstname>
      <Surname>string</Surname>
      <IcNew>string</IcNew>
    </memberReservedTransactions>
  </memberReservedTransactionRequest>
</U_MemberReservedTransaction>
```

Just to summarize what the service is expecting, the service is to receive an array of memberReservedTransactions. My SOAP request call looks like below currently.

```
$client->callService('U_MemberReservedTransaction', array(
    'UserID'=>'test1',
    'password'=>'password',
    'memberReservedTransactionRequest' => array( 
    'memberReservedTransaction' => array (
     array( 
        'ReservedType'=>'Renew', 
        'Firstname'=>'', 
                'Surname'=>'',
        'IcNew'=>''
            )
         )
     )
```

));

As for what i'm expecting in return is a multidimensional array but my concern now is getting my request accepted.

Note : I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error

Please help :<